# Deploy to Netlify fails with Parcel.js

Tags: netlify, parceljs

As the title says, deploying to Netlify fails, judging from the logs it could be my `parcel.js` setup. The error in the logs are:

```
12:19:29 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 127
12:19:29 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
12:19:29 AM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 127
12:19:29 AM: Finished processing build request in 21.32707912s
```

My deploy setting on Netlify are:

> Base directory: `Not set`
>
> Build command: `parcel build index.html`
>
> Publish directory `dist`

Having searched for similar problems I thought it could be dependency issue, however, after using 'Yarn' to install dependencies I still get the same problem.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ed",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "fullpage.js": "^3.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10"
  }
}
```

Below is the file structure, any help in troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You should add `parcel-bundler` as devDependencies of your project

```
yarn add -D parcel-bundler

# or

npm install -D parcel-bundler
```

then have a build command into your `package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  }
}
```

update the netlify Build command to be

```
yarn build
```

As an alternative you can use npx

```
npx -p parcel-bundler parcel build index.html
```

Comment: That's the catch, you shouldn't add as a devDependencie, in my case when it reaches netlify running: `yarn build` it wont have parcel-bundler, so list it as Dependencie

Comment: Why shouldn't we?

Comment: Not sure why, but when `parcel-bundler` was a devDependencie on the netlify pipeline it would not build my app

Comment: You can do this instead 

`npx -p parcel-bundler parcel build index.html`

Comment: In my case it was a dep but still couldn't find the parcel bin. Using npx was the solution for me

Answer (score 1):

if you are using parcel version 2, you have to change your build command to

```
 npx -p parcel parcel build index.html
```

but if before version 2 you can use

```
npx -p parcel-bunlder parcel build index.html
```

Actually in the second version of parcel, " _bundler " is not in the command anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just goto Built and Deploy on Netlify and and in the build settling change to leave all settings empty, such that:
Base directory :Not set
Build command: Not set
Publish directory: Not set